# Unable to update PATH variable for pip on Windows 10

Tags: python, path, pip

I know there are thousands of similar topics but my pip command has suddenly stopped to work and, despite all my researchs, I can't figure out why. It has been a while since I last used pip and surprisingly my computer doesn't recognize the command anymore. I reinstalled pip and the prompt tells me that the PATH variable is not correctly updated. So I update it but that doesn't solve the problem, the prompt still tells me the PATH variable is not updated. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling python and pip and nothing works.
In my environment variables, I have a user variable named PATH and a system variable named PATH, both of them have the value :
`C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\`

The user variable was already written by itself and I had to write the system variable myself.

When I'm installing pip I get this warning :

> WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.6.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
>     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

And when I type pip in the command prompt, it tells me that pip is not recognized.

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done that in a new command prompt or an existing one? Any open existing command prompts will still have the old PATH so make sure you've tried the command in a *newly opened* prompt?

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you the problem is solved ! One hour of searching for such a simple solution, I'm a little bit disappointed aha

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, at one time: I could only use administrative privileges to use python `cmd` or `pip easy_install`.

PLEASE follow these procedures:

1. Get to your environmental variables by pressing `window` + `r` and type-in, `sysdm.cpl` and click ok.
2. Copy the pip link directory to the script folder in python,
   but first check for `pip`, `pip3`, `easy_easy`, etc. 
   If it doesn't contain `pip`, you have to uninstall python and delete the folder, and then reinstall python.

i.e

> C:\Users\mickeymouse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts.

3. You will see user variables and system variables.
   (user variables are applied for only that user's account; system variable are applied to all accounts on the pc).

Create a path for both, then restart `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a specialist in Pip or Python, but I faced a similar problem and used a different procedure.

I believe Pip cached directories depend on user permissions during installation and update.

At first, the Pip installer defaults to the Python home directory for caching files. If such a directory is unreachable, the installer creates a cached directory inside the current user's home directory.

Since Python includes Pip by default, the issue reported should not happen at the first install, yet it is due to trying to run the update without administrative privileges.

If that is the case, you could try the following steps:

1. Assert the system PATH has proper Python directories assigned, e.g.:

- `C:\Program Files\Python310\` for Python executable files;
- `C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\` for Python scripts and extensions.

2. Remove Pip's registered cached directories using the command `py -m pip cache purge.`
3. Search for and remove any Pip content outside the Python subdirectory. For example, you could check for contents such as `[user home directory]\.pip` and `[user home directory]\pip.`
4. Remove Pip references from the system and the user PATH variables.
5. Open Windows Terminal with administrator privileges and rerun the Pip installer command. You should **not** use the `--no-warn-script-location` option, or else you will not be able to see if there is any unexpected behavior.

Finally, to my knowledge, Pip's documentation lacks a consistent reference for directory options. Anyway, the following links provided me with some clarity:

Pip general reference:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/

On Pip caching strategies:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/

On Pip caching problems, including older versions:
https://www.techiediaries.com/python-pip-local-cache/

All the best!