# set up path in a webjob azure

Tags: azure, webjob

I try to do to following:

```
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;D:\home\python364x86\Lib\site-packages"
```

But I am getting the following:

> ERROR: Access to the registry path is denied.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the PATH is not straightforward, but possible.

You could use the code as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <add name="FOO" value="BAR" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
        <add name="PATH" value="%PATH%;%HOME%\FolderOnPath" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
      </environmentVariables>
    </runtime> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#adding-environment-variables).

Comment: After trying to install pip I get: WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.6.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'D:\local\AppData\Python\Python36\Scripts' which is not on PATH

Comment: Please refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519317/unable-to-update-path-variable-for-pip-on-windows-10).